# How can we show the following metric regularity property (in the context of constrained optimization)

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, constraints

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, $g\in C^1(X,Y)$ and $\overline x\in X$ such that ${\rm D}g(\overline x)$ is surjective.

In Lemma 2.32 of [this](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~bonnans/notes/oc/ocbook.pdf) lecture notes, the following claim is made: There exists $c_g>0$ such that, if $x\in X$ is close enough to $\overline x$, there exists $x'\in X$ such that $$\left\|x'-x\right\|_X\le c_g\left\|g(x)\right\|_Y\text{ and }g(x')=0.\tag1$$

First of all: How exactly is the "if $x$ is close enough to $\overline x$" part influencing $(1)$? Does the author mean that there exists $c_g,\varepsilon>0$ such that $(1)$ holds for all $x\in B_\varepsilon(\overline x)$?

If the statement of the claim is clarified: How can we prove it? Unfortunately the author is only giving a reference in French.

Comment: That certainly isn't true without additional assumptions. For example the exponential map (on $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ depending on what type of Banach space you are looking at) always has surjective (in fact, invertible) differential at any point, but the exponential map does not admit any point $x'$ for which $\exp(x')=0$, the other part of the consequence also seems to need $g(x')=0$.

Comment: @s.harp So the claim in the reference is wrong? (I don't know what you mean by "the other part of the consequence also seems to need $g(x')=0$"; $g(x')=0$ is part of $(1)$ ...

Comment: Point (1) has two parts, one is an inequality and the other is $g(x')=0$. As you have written it the statement is false, as demonstrated by easy counter examples. There may be other assumptions hidden in the text. For example the author may be assuming $g$ to take on the value $0$.

Comment: Even assuming that $g$ has a zero allows for counter examples. I think one can show that the statement is true (the proofs in these cases look elementary) if $g$ admits a zero and $g(\overline x)\neq0$ or if $g$ admits a zero and $Dg(\overline x)$ is an isomorphism. That doesn't seem so interesting. If I were you I would look at how this Lemma is used to find out what its actual assumptions are.